# NameError: name 'dbutils' is not defined

Tags: pyspark, conda, databricks, mlflow

I've .py file with following code line and it lives in git.

```
dbutils.widgets.text(name='CORPORATION_ID', defaultValue='1234')
```

I am using mlflow to run it in remote databricks job cluster. I've conda.yml and MLProject file to pick it up from git and run it in databricks job cluster but I am getting following error.

```
  File "tea/src/cltv_xgb_tea.py", line 40, in <module>
    dbutils.widgets.text(name='CORPORATION_ID', defaultValue='1234')
NameError: name 'dbutils' is not defined
```

Any help/solution is much appreciated.

---

My current files in git

Conda.yml has

```
name: cicd-environment
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pip=19.0.3
  - pip:
    - mlflow==1.7.2
    - DBUtils==1.3
    - ipython==7.14.0
    - databricks-connect==6.5.1
    - invoke==1.4.1
    - awscli==1.18.87
```

Comment: Are you running this file locally, on your own instance of Spark?

Comment: I am running it on databricks job cluster. Not locally.